# MKMapView center and span not consistent

Tags: ios, iphone

I have whittled my issue down to this:
1.  I created a new project with mapkit framework and maps capabilities.
2.  I added #import MapKit/MapKit.h to my ...controller.h
3.  I put two MKMapViews on my storyboard (one at .5 alpha) and two buttons.
4.  And then here is my ...controller.m:

```
#import "MapTestViewController.h"

@interface MapTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)pressedbutton200:(id)sender {
    _mapView1.frame= CGRectMake(75, 75, 150, 150);
    _mapView2.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
   _mapView1.region= MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.406206, -77.224446), 200, 200);
   _mapView2.region= MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.406206, -77.224446), 400, 400);
}
- (IBAction)pressedbutton20000:(id)sender {
    _mapView1.frame= CGRectMake(75, 75, 150, 150);
    _mapView2.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
   _mapView1.region= MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.406206, -77.224446), 20000, 20000);
   _mapView2.region= MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.406206, -77.224446), 40000, 40000);
}
@end
```

Pressing button200 gives this:
[image: Button200 pressed]
Pressing button20000 gives this:
[image]
The images appear to be shifted in both lat and lon and even span.

Question:
1. Why are the images not lined up and at the same span?

The reasons that I think they should line up pixel for pixel are that both mapviews have the same center on the screen, they are told to draw at the same center coordinates and the pixel scale of both mapViews should be the same as mapView2 is twice as large on the screen as mapView1 and mapView2 is filled at twice the span of mapView1.

They seem to be shifted in lat for sure and the center lon seems OK, but lons away from center lon are not OK.

Also the shift is about the same screen pixels using both buttons which are drawn at different map spans.

If it matters at all, I think the smaller mapView1 is the correct image because the coordinates I used are the center of the street intersection, according to Google Earth, and that intersection is pixel centered in the smaller map view.

I hope I have reduced this issue to as simple a case as I can.
Thanks, Carmen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this just appears to be the way of the Apple beast.
I have switched to Google Maps API and I am VERY happy.  None of the above nonsense.
I get maps that actually have a center point in the pixel center of the map view and I can specify a precise zoom level and actually obtain it.
An added benefit is that I can draw the map at any heading and it fills up the map view, it doesn't leave empty corners on the view like I was rotating a paper map on a table.
Carmen